# Is this possible using LEAD or is there a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm wanting to return the dataset below from 2 tables. Table A will have temperature readings and table B will have Humidity readings. They will also have timestamps in each table so for instance like this:

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

Basically I'm wanting the output to get me the Temperature and the next closest Humidity reading to that temperature timestamp. So for instance the output would look like this:

[image]

So I'm wanting to start with Table A and then find the next closest following record for the same sensor in Table B based on timestamp.

Comment: how should the tables be joined?

Comment: I'm guessing on Trailer and Zone since that is what I'm wanting to get the reading for.

Comment: Neither table has `humidity`.  How is that calculated?

Comment: That was my mistake I corrected Table B now.

Comment: Do all temps have a coorsponding humidity or could there be gaps in one or the other such that a hmidity reading or temp reading may be tied to more than 1 of the other?

Comment: See where this is going @JoeStarnes? We really need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks like the time interval regarding the `Temp` and `Humidity` is `Temp Time + 1 = Humidity Time`. Is this always the case?

Comment: There could possibly be gaps.... but I'm looking to start with my temp datatset which come in at 5 minute intervals and then find the 'closest' humidity reading in table B based on trailer, zone, timestamp.   There could be gaps in humidity readings which would be fine.

Comment: closest (above or below) or always above? and in case of ties choose the one above or below or both?

Comment: below... so if temp was record at 1:50:34 and then there was a humidity reading at 1:51:50 it would grab that humidity..... and in case of a tie it could record the record that was the tie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a cross apply here.  Example: http://rextester.com/RGPS53348  or http://rextester.com/EKDX38312 with closer times

Essentially for each record in A, Find the record in B with matching trailer and zone and the one with the closest time

This should return the "Closest time" for humidity in relation to the time for the temperature and in case of ties, return the earlier time/record from humidity.

```
SELECT A.Trailer, A.Zone, A.temp, B.Humidity, A.Time A_time, B.Time B_Time
FROM tableA A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Top 1 Z.* 
             FROM tableB  Z
             WHERE A.Trailer = Z.Trailer
               and A.Zone = Z.Zone
             --ORDER BY abs(A.Time- Z.Time) Asc, Z.Time) B --if int data
             ORDER BY abs(datediff(ss,A.Time,Z.Time)),Z.time) B --
```

The query basically says..

- For each record in A, run the sub query to find the record with the time closest to the time  [abs(A.time-Z.time)] on the A Record having the same trailer and zone.
- In the case of ties, return the earlier b record.
- Display the A record's trailer, zone, temp, and time and the b record's humidity and time.

Comment: In the last line the query does not like the B.Time.... is that supposed to be Z.Time?  I'm also returning the following error   "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to float is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query"

Comment: Yes, it is.  my error; and corrected on the b.time order by.  As for the other error, I assumed time was a numeric since your example showed numbers; but the comments seem to imply it's a time data type.  what is it?  datetime or time? or what?  if a date data type we need to use `abs(datediff(n,A.Time, B.Time))`  or we can get more granular if seconds matter.

Comment: most of the time the closest record would be roughly a second later, yes

Comment: HI all, had a small issue with this code today and wanted to see if there was a fix. In the cross apply if there is no record in table B to match the record in A is there a way to return that record? if even with NULLs from B?

Comment: I believe you want to use `OUTER APPLY` instead of cross apply then.  Be sure your where clause (on the outer join) , if you have one, doesn't filter by any results from B or the outer apply will be treated as a cross apply.  Instead apply those filters within the subquery. where. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f2eb371a-78af-43d3-bdf6-be046cfa9341/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-usage?forum=transactsql  CROSS apply is similar to inner join and OUTER apply is similar to a LEFT join.  In the future separate questions should be asked once an answer has been accepted

Comment: I would ask a new question refer back to the orginal question via a link and pose the new problem being encountered; include sample data and expected results as you did in this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first_value` window function to do this.

```
select distinct a.*
,first_value(b.humidity) over(partition by a.trailer,a.zone,a.time order by b.time) as humidity
from tblA a
join tblB b on a.trailer=b.trailer and a.zone=b.zone and a.time<=b.time
```

Use a `left join` on tableA if you want to show `null`s if no such humidity values exist at a later time in tableB.